# Proving the planarity or non-planarity of this graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm having trouble knowing whether this graph is planar or nonplanar - a seven vertex graph with each vertex of degree 4.

[image]

So it's planar if e ≤ 3v - 6, and there are 14 edges and 7 vertices, so 14 ≤ 15. So it is planar then? I can't seem to find any way this would be planar, and if it is nonplanar, I can't find a sensible k3,3 configuration.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: It is **not** true that if $e\leq 3v-6$ then the graph is planar (for example $K_{3,3}$ satisfies $e\leq 3v-6$ but it is not planar). It is the converse that is true: If the graph is planar, then $e\leq 3v-6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph is not planar:  there is a $K_5$ subgraph formed by merging, for example, vertices $A, B, C$ together.

Comment: I think you mean minor, rather than subgraph, and if you merge vertices $A$,$B$,$C$ you get $K_5 - e$, since $G$ and $D$ are non-adjacent.

Comment: @PerryElliott-Iverson Yes, you are correct.  I wrote the above response rather hastily.